# if $\cos a_1 = \sin a_1 \cos a_2 = \sin a_2 \cos a_3 = \cdots = \sin a_{n-1}\cos a_n = \sin a_n $. How to find the value of $\cos a_1$?

Tags: trigonometry

if $\cos a_1 = \sin a_1 \cos a_2 = \sin a_2 \cos a_3 = \cdots = \sin a_{n-1}\cos a_n = \sin a_n$ and $ a_1, \cdots a_n \in (0, {\pi \over 2})$, $n \geq 2$. How to find the value of  $\cos a_1$?

I will appreciate it if you can help me solve this question.

This question is about another question as below:

$${\max \big({ x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_3x_4 + \cdots + x_{n-1}x_n \over x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + \cdots +x_n^2 }\big)} \tag{1}$$

First, I try to scale the denominator. For example, when $n=4$, we can find that
$$
\begin{align*} &{x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 +x_3x_4 \over (x_1^2 + {\lambda x_2^2}) + ({(1-\lambda) x_2^2} + {\mu x_3^2}) + {((1-\mu)x_3^2} +x_4^2)}\\ & \leq {x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 +x_3x_4 \over 2\sqrt \lambda x_1x_2 +2 \sqrt{(1-\lambda)\mu}x_2x_3 +  2 \sqrt {1-\mu} x_3x_4 } \end{align*}
$$
Then we assume that
$$2\sqrt \lambda = 2 \sqrt{(1-\lambda)\mu}=2\sqrt{1-\mu}$$
Express the above formula in the form of trigonometric function:
$$
2\cos \alpha = 2\sin \alpha \cos\beta = 2\sin\beta
$$
So, we can easily find that the $\cos \alpha $ is ${\sqrt 5 -1 \over  2}$ , but when there are $n$ factors, it's too difficult. So I give it up and find another method to solve this question(quadratic form, Chebyshev polynomial), but I'm still curious how this will continue...

the answer of $(1)$ is $\cos({\pi \over n+1})$, so I can deduce that the value of the $\cos a_1$ is ${1 \over 2\cos({\pi \over n+2})}$

Comment: From $\cos a_1=\sin a_n$ and $0<a_1,a_n<\frac\pi2$, we get $$a_1+a_n=\frac\pi2.$$  Therefore, $\sin a_1=\cos a_n$ as well.  Now $\sin a_1\cos a_2=\sin a_{n-1}\cos a_n$ along with $\sin a_1=\cos a_n$ implies $\cos a_2=\sin a_{n-1}$.   You continue to do this and get $$a_k+a_{n+1-k}=\frac\pi2$$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.   This should make the task a lot easier since the number of free variables is halved.